# Loop Request In Java Android

Tags: java, android, json

Here I am getting my data in comma seperated format.

```
1,2,3,4....n
```

Response ids are more than 300.

```
requestButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.requestButton);
```

I want to take first 45 on button click, then again next 45 on button click and so on.
Ids should not repeat.

Is there any way how can I do that.

```
try {
    JSONObject rob = response.getJSONObject();

    JSONArray array = rob.getJSONArray("data");
    fr = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

        friend = array.getJSONObject(i);




        fr.add(friend.get("id"));




        formatedString = fr.toString()
            .replace("[", "")
            .replace("]", "");

        Log.d("uid", String.valueOf(formatedString));

    }


} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass count as parameter in your url .Thats will fetch data from server(you have to create code). Then if you want more  call the same url with increased count.

first time

```
url="http://androidexample.com/getPage.php?count=45";
```

when more button clicked  call the same url with increased count

```
url="http://androidexample.com/getPage.php?count=90";
```

another way  is store all the value in local database when first time data loaded from server then display listview based on the count.